# Why does my 12-month-old baby gravitate towards my side at night, even though he prefers his mother overall?

Tags: infant, sleep, bed-sharing

I am aware that a child preferring one parent over the other is nothing unusual. My son mostly has a bias for his mother. She can suite him more easily, put him to sleep a lot more easily and he notices her being gone a lot quicker.

At night for some reason, he tends to gravitate towards my side of the bed (he sleeps in the middle), even placing his head on top of.

What could be the reason for this? It seems to be fairly common.

He also moves to my position in advance before I go to bed.

Comment: Just a guess, but possibly higher body temperature due to increased [metabolic rate](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC329930/) in men.

Comment: doesn't have to be more complicated that he has a 50/50 chance to either roll over towards the left or towards the right. People tend to roll over in the same direction. You just happen to be there

Comment: Do you were similar kinds of clothing? Are you similar types of sleepers? -how much you move, what position you take, how much you tolerate being touched...etc etc. Knowing why he likes anything is probably unguessable, wait a year and if he still does ask him.

Answer (score 14):

You're probably heavier, make a bigger dent in the mattress and he follows gravity towards you.  That's my hypothesis.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely it's one of the reasons already given, such as luck of the draw, warmer, or you make the bed bend more, but if you want to have a feel good answer here you go.

He feels protected and safe around you. He may not show it during the day, but at night it's a little scary. So being close to big, tough daddy is more comforting for him.